# Complexity of matrix multiplication over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, algorithms, finite-fields

I've been reading about theoretical bounds on the computational complexity of $n\times n$ matrix-matrix multiplication in floating-point arithmetic, about how the complexity is known to fall between $\mathcal O(n^2)$ and $\mathcal O(n^3)$, and how the exponent has been slowly whittled down over time by various researchers. It's currently unknown whether a $\mathcal O(n^2)$ algorithm is possible.

I was wondering about what the complexity of multiplying two bit-matrices over the finite field $\mathbb F_2$ (or other finite fields - my intuition tells me the complexity will be the same), but I haven't found any references online. Are there any known "tricks" for multiplying matrices in $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ that makes it less expensive than multiplication in larger fields or in floating point? What current bounds are known? Is there a known $\mathcal O(n^2)$ algorithm? Can anyone provide any relevant references for these sort of questions?

Comment: This is a good and interesting question. In case it doesn't get answered here, you could also always try computer science stackexchange https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or if no answer there then maybe even https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/  Apparently even for reals, you can do slightly better than otherwise possible if you have sparse matrices: https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-algorithm-breaks-speed-limit-for-solving-linear-equations-20210308/ So I think it is quite reasonable to expect that, given even more special structure, e.g. like $\mathbb{F}_2$, faster algorithms could be possible.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is no more efficient to multiply over $\mathbb{F}_2$ compared to over $\mathbb{R}$ unless you have sparse matrices or special structure.

Even though there are efficient algorithms for certain arithmetic and polynomial operations over finite fields (and in particular $\mathbb{F}_2$ this efficiency does not seem to extend to make an asymptotic difference in the complexity of matrix multiplication.

See the [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62695/is-there-a-fast-way-to-compute-matrix-multiplication-mod-p) in mathoverflow to a similar question for more details, I will quote a small part from there below:

> For $\mathbb{F}_2$ (and other finite fields of characteristic $2$) there is a specialized library for computing with matrices over that structure.

> It is called M4RI. In particular, a paper by developpers of the library: Martin Albrecht, Gregory Bard, William Hart. Algorithm 898: Efficient Multiplication of Dense Matrices over GF(2). ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software 2010.

> Preprint at http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1714.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @pcpthm for pointing this out, the claim below for the average complexity would not hold over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in such generality. Since the result over boolean algebras may still be of interest I will let the paragraph below stand.

*However, due to the special structure of $\mathbb{F}_2,$ one can actually prove that **on average** matrix multiplication can be performed with complexity
$O(n^{2+\varepsilon})$ elementary operations by a randomized algorithm, see [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/273276/1-s2.0-S0019995800X00356/1-s2.0-S0019995873902283/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEH8aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHyAP5aAWz3id4s%2Bmaxw2NgcjeQrk8oGAP5KI3ZpjS4WAiAxd8O1qgbPW4jVPrTWjB7isqXKRz26RQbG7LbzY%2FKfpiqDBAjI%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMhzvjSr524KwHJNAFKtcD4W6%2B85KXnuLbgYj%2Bnfe6RWYk0v%2BBhgDhXYPTfeNeaALTXiR75nMZENL2iA0h%2BnAWJL92GtrFHoCFl6eFKw%2BIsbX7ZsYobIVCtx4t3Yb96vy2iN%2B6hwbyh1jk2YXCsde5vAjgo5MdGk0bTHT6rGrr3i37LvCKQa%2BVY%2BoEUt5RD6bWwhSCyhvJ6kfIpXRDmRqxzZZnUwAwVSQLeMlpK9Uc65%2Bf2QLvJE%2FCtSfzqsMG6qNOOSCccu4nEXOu0sj%2FN4bn%2BdWOFVcE%2BLVtzlxcNE7kLw7olWaAmfxK3YqaarP24kXuFeh8LjknmCdjOAWgg5uYYJr7myfvTG%2FnQlXmbFABRFWCTE0LdYv%2FV2A12ZeuC2ZybcbWoxr4apoAQs%2F2AHSx%2FFVvbN5mECOcgCglgsy0Cvlb0XxfigloAVg4QM3zPbeDBFeVViika2dK9Z9EIab4HcB2M%2FoHCqCfwaU5ErI7n6Tb9M0%2BX7SiLJKnZccn2fDbBjlBtONvNESNNcueHvdlGOC%2BpHn0yFB32jlz3JI0zzU%2F8QyaG1r1pJdaHtiHep64rEHRJvkS7jqfRqkz4NORhRX9d6HZ8a62MNJJ5n3wJ2QMFuusYntp9M92PSfFrXLBzwSkxPmrMOn6tZAGOqYBxABJZlQ6IEDF%2F26Fo6r7gHuGHAUrM%2F0hZ4WA34jWey7Hzhor6SJASy3ivNzdhqUEcb7z6%2FrxZYVOWO2cDtNXrRimUsBVZpmMtL%2Fg1UyrI7L6SSUVSynXkKbktvj4wa6B2%2BkgQhCG18zquw2daV6u47erUfdioPxBBifKRq4BAvmQ40ofPxNEU4O2%2ByRkFNPq6suiJqZWdqpi%2Fy2aK806R7JWN8RStA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220216T235237Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY347S7T4F%2F20220216%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=867ae50406a2342eecd46d27fa5e56c26cdbd0d50265563f26aba8a78d56bc07&hash=c6430ec974812cb4610a7fa95f746680b15f15c5257e1b1e847d7398bc0acb62&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0019995873902283&tid=spdf-7e4d960f-6bff-4403-ac34-b916c30a09bc&sid=16f6d1448ec5514bed9b9fb002158060f48bgxrqa&type=client&ua=4c00020001540650055c&rr=6deab0d2a93a5db6).*

Comment: It looks like the algorithm presented in the linked paper assumes Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B}$ (AND, OR), not $\mathbb{F}_2$ (XOR, AND).